# AWS cloudwatch webhook or api

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, webhooks, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I am new with AWS and I m trying to find a way to get alarms from cloud watch. I set up an SNS topic and set a server endpoint but I relize that this needs confirmation of subscription.Do you know how to set up the webhook or if there is a call for getting alarms?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to CloudWatch
2. Choose Alarms from the left menu
3. Create Alarm
4. Select your metric
5. Specify metric and conditions then next
6. In the `Configure actions` part `you may select an SNS Topic` from the dropdown list.
7. Fill name, description on the next step
8. Preview and create.

Edit:

For subscription part; i've created a topic and a lambda for it's subscription  which will get SNS event and send it to slack. There are other options such as http(s) calls, email, sms etc.